# Create a vector with values corresponding to a separate matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Using MATLAB, I would like to create a new vector, in which the values in the original vector are replaced by corresponding numbers from another matrix.

Specifically, I have a large vector `(30,000 x 1)` in which the individual values in each cell correspond to locations in the brain `(range: 0 - 166)`. These values are somewhat randomly spread across the vector (they correspond to brain locations). After running an experiment, I would now like to replace each instance of these values with a value that I've calculated experimentally. These values are stored in a corresponding matrix `(167 x 2)`: the first column contains the value from the original matrix `(0 - 166)` and the second column contains the new value I'd like to replace the original value `(0 - 6)`. So for example, if value `150` was associated with a score of `5` in my experiment, I'd like to replace each instance of `150` with a `5` in the original matrix.

original vector: `[1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; ...]`

identity matrix: `[0 0; 1 4; 2 5; 3 2; ...]`

new vector: `[4; 4; 4; 4; 5; 5; 5; 5; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 5; 5; 5; 5; ...]`

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
originalMatrix = [1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 0; 3];
identityMatrix = [0 0; 1 4; 2 5; 3 2];
[~,ind] = ismember(originalMatrix,identityMatrix(:,1));
map = identityMatrix(:,2);
result = map(ind);
```

**Edit**

> I keep getting this error: "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

It's because some values in `originalMatrix` don't have corresponding values in `identityMatrix`.

so you can ignore them by,

```
ind(ind==0) = [];
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I've given it a try, but I keep getting this error:

"Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Answer (score 2):

```
indCol=identityMatrix(:,2);
newVector=indCol(originalVector+1)
```

Or, in one line:

```
newVector=identityMatrix(originalVector+168)
```

Comment: If the `identity matrix` is sorted without missing values, this will work. good answer.

Comment: He said it's 167x2. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way, but this should get the job done.
For every value in the range 0-166 i find the indexes of the original vector components which contains that value. This is stored in the vector called Indexes. Then I put the new value  called identity_matrix(i,2) in new_vector at this Indexes.

```
new_vector = zeros(size(original_vector));
for i = 1:167
    Indexes = find(original_vector == identity_matrix(i,1));
    new_vector(Indexes) = identity_matrix(i,2);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using `bsxfun` and multiplication (with the data from Kamtal's answer):

```
originalMatrix = [1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 0; 3];
identityMatrix = [0 0; 1 4; 2 5; 3 2];
result = bsxfun(@eq,originalMatrix(:),identityMatrix(:,1)')*identityMatrix(:,2);
```